# Increment self variable from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have self variable total in a list and want to update the value using a for loop.

However what I've tried doesn't increase the total.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

        self.list = [self.total,
                     self.total]

        for item in self.list:
            item += 5

        print(self.total)

Example()
```

The printed output in the example is 0, whereas I'm wanting to know what I need to change to get this to equal 10.

Many thanks

Comment: you are not modifying `self.total `

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables like `int`, `float` `str` and `tuple` are not mutables and are passed around by value. Therefore

```
self.list = [self.total, self.total]
```

is equivalent to

```
self.list = [0, 0]
```

and where `0` is the number zero and not a references to `self.total`. So when you do:

```
for item in self.list:
    item += 5
```

in each iteration you initialize the variable `item` to `0`, then increase it by 5. Since you alway do the same, at the end of the loop `item` will always be 5, independently of the number of iterations. And `self.total` is never modified.

If you want to increase `self.total` you have to do it explicitly:

```
for i in range(2):
    self.total += 5
```

---

**EDIT** according to the comment below

It is possible to modify variables in place when using mutables, e.g. `list`. A possible solution to your problem might be:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total1, self.total2 = [], []
        self.list = [self.total1, self.total2, self.total1]

        for item in self.list:
            item.append(5)
        print(sum(self.total1), sum(self.total2))
```

If you don't what to do sums at the end, in the for loop you can use `list.pop` and `list.append` to remove the existing value from `item`, update it and re-insert it into `item`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to increment self.total without doing so explicitly? This was just an example to demonstrate, The real list has many different variables and I wanted to update them without explicitly coding eaching one.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. Do you mean that, if you have e.g. ``self.total1``, ``self.total2`` and ``self.list = [self.total1, self.total1, self.total2``, the expected result is ``self.total1 ==10`` and ``self.total2 == 5``?

Comment: Yes. I would want to update `self.total1` and `self.total2` without explicitly coding `self.total1 += 5` or `self.total2 += 5`. If that is possible

Comment: @blountdj: I've edited my answer with a possible solution

Comment: glad to have been helpful and thank you for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

**try this:-**

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

        self.list = [self.total,
                     self.total]

        for item in self.list:
            item += 5
            self.total += item

        print(self.total)

Example()
```